# Call a layout of android library

Tags: android

I Created an android library with a layout ,

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Test Library" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

I added this library in another android project 
How can i call what i created in layout of the library ?
It's my first experience with android library , so thank you for your help

Comment: did you just try to import the R class from your library?

Comment: When you say "library", are you importing this as a JAR file, an AAR bundle, or importing the source as a "library project"?

Comment: @Yjay I imported it as library project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Package_A= Contains the XML layout.

Package_A = The library. So right click on Package_A, go to "properties". Then go to "Android". Make sure the "Is Library" is checked.

Package_B= References Package_A. So right click on Package_A, go to "properties". Then go to "Android". Make sure the "Is Library" is not checked and that u added Package_A as a Reference.

No you can use the XML from Package_B. Just call it normally.

```
setContentView(R.layout.package_a_layout);
```